# Sorting '£' (pound symbol) in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, utf-8, oracle11g

I am trying to sort `£` along with other special characters, but its not sorting properly.

I want that string to be sorted along with other strings starting with special characters. For example I have four strings:

1. `&!@#`
2. `££$$`
3. `abcd`
4. `&#$%`.

Now its sorting in the order: `&!@#, &#$%, abcd, ££$$`. 
I want it in the order: `&!@#, &#$%, ££$$, abcd`.

I have used the function order by `replace(column,'£','*')` so that it sorts along with strings starting with `*`. Although this seems to work while querying the DB, when used in code and deployed the `£` gets replaced by `ï¿½`, i.e. `(replace(column,'ï¿½','*')` in the query, and doesn't sort as expected.

How to resolve this issue? Is there any other solution to sort the pound symbol/£? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `its not sorting properly` --- no one except you knows here what `proper sorting` means. Explain the question in a way everyone could get you without additional questions

Comment: As I have mentioned, I want the '£' symbol to be sorted along with other special characters. All other characters are sorting properly as of now.

Comment: omg, what does `I want the '£' symbol to be sorted along with other special characters`??

Comment: Strings starting with '£' symbol. I thought that was understood. Sorry if u had issues in understanding that

Comment: Strings start with pound symbol. So? 1 hour passed and you still didn't explain what's wrong with sorting

Comment: I want that string to be sorted along with other strings starting with special characters. For eg I have four strings: 1. &!@# 2.££$$ 3.abcd 4 &#$%. Now its sorting in the order: &!@#, &#$%,abcd,££$$. I want it in the order: &!@#, &#$%, ££$$, abcd    . Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Apparently SQL Server sorts the way you want. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/123277/ What DBMS do you use?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using Oracle 11g. But it's not sorting like that? Any way to get around it? it treats '£' different to other special characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have two problems; performing the actual sort, and (possibly) how the £ symbol appears in the results in your code. Without knowing anything about your code or client or environment it's rather hard to guess what you might need to change, but I'd start by looking at your NLS_LANG and other NLS settings at the client end. @amccausl's link might be useful, but it depends what you're doing. I suspect you'll find different values in `nls_session_parameters` when queried from SQL*Plus and from your code, which may give you some pointers.

The sorting itself is slightly clearer now. Have a look at the docs for [Linguistic Sorting and String Searching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm) and [`NLSSORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions113.htm).

You can do something like this (with a CTE to generate your data):

```
with tmp_tab as (
    select '&!@#' as value from dual
    union all select '££$$' from dual
    union all select 'abcd' from dual
    union all select '&#$%' from dual
)
select * from tmp_tab
order by nlssort(value, 'NLS_SORT = WEST_EUROPEAN')

VALUE
------
&!@#
&#$%
££$$
abcd

4 rows selected.
```

You can get sort values supported by your configuration with `select value from v$nls_valid_values where parameter = 'SORT'`, but `WESTERN_EUROPEAN` seems to do what you want, for this sample data anyway.

You can see the default sorting in your current session with `select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_SORT'`. (You can change that with an `ALTER SESSION`, but it's only letting me do that with some values, so that may not be helpful here).

Comment: H, Thanks very much for the help. Sorry for being late to reply. the query "order by nlssort(value, 'NLS_SORT = WEST_EUROPEAN')" did work. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your application code is all proper UTF-8 (see http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html for more details)

Comment: Sorry I coudn't make out what to do from the link. Could you tell me how to make sure of that?

Comment: it's likely that your connection encoding on the database is set differently then the encoding in your code.  What language?  What database?  The doc includes information about configuring an environment to handle encoding properly, from the database to the code.  Following it will likely fix your problem, but you won't know what the problem is until you've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your issue is with db characterset, or difference in charactersets between the app and db.  For Oracle side, you can check by doing:

```
select value from sys.nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

If this comes up ascii (like US7ASCII), then you may have issues storing the data properly.  Even if this is the charset, you should be able to insert and retrieve sorted (binary sort) by using nvarchar2 and unistr (assuming they conform to your NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET, see above query but change parameter), like:

```
create table test1(val nvarchar2(100));
insert into test1(val) values (unistr('\00a3')); -- pound currency
insert into test1(val) values (unistr('\00a5')); -- yen currency
insert into test1(val) values ('$'); -- dollar currency
commit;

select * from test1
order by val asc;
```

-- will give symbols in order: dollar('\0024'), pound ('\00a3'), yen ('\00a5')

I will say that I would not resort to using the national characterset, I would probably change the db characterset to fit the needs of my data, as supporting 2 diff character sets isn't ideal, but its available anyway

If you have no issues storing/retrieving on the data side, then your app/client characterset is probably different than your db.

Answer (score 0):

Use nchar(168). It will work.

> select nchar(168)